# How can I fix this IlleagalstateException on accessing restful spring-boot application deployed on Tomcat?

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot, tomcat8, restful-authentication

I am getting `threw exception
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: getWriter() has already been called for this response
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getOutputStream(Response.java:544)`

while communicating my server side code (RESTFul, Spring-boot) from angular2. Both are deployed on the same server (Tomcat 8.0.2).

The following is my code

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public User login() {
    Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    User user = (User) principal;

    return user;
}
```

How can fix this?

Comment: Tell us with code what you are trying to do . It looks like you are calling getWriter() once the writer is called.

Comment: I'm trying to do the restful basic authentication. When I login from my client i'm getting this exception. During login i'm returning the authenticated user from security context object

Comment: share minimal code please.

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public User login(Principal principal) {
    User user = (User) principal; // take care of the conversion!
    return user;
}
```

or

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public User login(Authentication authentication) {
    User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal(); // take care of the conversion!
    return user;
}
```

Comment: Ok Thanks. Will this fix my issue?

Comment: can you try and let us know. @Prince

Comment: It gives "org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken cannot be cast to org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User" Exception

Comment: you have to handle it. I doubted that conversion, populate as per the requirement